# Git clone access - Unable to paste key on command line

Tags: git, command-line, key, clone

Pasting key on command line seems to paste it line by line, instead of the entire key together.

And so every line of the key says `-bash keyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx command not found`
where `keyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` is one line of the key, and it shows up line by line, instead of just logging me in and enable me to git clone.

I have a private RSA Key in a text file

The file starts with:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and ends with:

```
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and in between there's a very long key of multiple lines (which as mentioned I haven't been able to paste as one password when attempting to git clone).

Comment: what key do you mean?

Comment: I have an RSA private key in a text file. See update to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont paste the key into your command line, you have to register your SSH key with your account on github (or whatever hosting service you are using).

See [this article](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) for how to do it on github, and read up on ssh keys in general (i.e. google, or that article, or both)

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but now I'm getting a message in my command line `Hi mygitusername! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.` why is that? and how do I git clone then?

Comment: you have to use git to clone, not ssh in first. Since you seem to be very new to git, you should read some introduction like [the Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book)

Comment: @LucyWeatherford, that means your SSH client managed to successfully log into the github server. Since Git client uses SSH client to carry out its work, it (the Git client) should work OK now, please try.

Comment: @LucyWeatherford, and what OS is that? I assume you're using Windows, and in this case I'd recommend to follow ["An Illustrated Guide to Git on Windows"](http://nathanj.github.io/gitguide/index.html). Otherwise the exact actions to carry out depend on your setup.

Comment: @kostix I'm using a Mac. And I want to fetch (or pull) the latest from github, but I still can't seem to login. Every time I try a new clone or a fetch I am asked for a username and password. I have the username, but the password is I was told is this RSA Key, but it seems to want a shorter answer

Comment: @LucyWeatherford, thanks. The process is as follows. If you *only* need to fetch (or pull, it's fetch + merge) then just use what is indicated as "read-only URL" on the project's github page -- this won't require SSH access and usage of the key. Othewise you will need to put the *private* part of your key in the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file and its *public* part in the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file. After that, calling `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` once per login session would cache the key so Git won't ask the password again.

Comment: The git only has a read-write access for me - it is a private repo and it is in my user.. The key text file only has a private part.

Comment: Never mind - I downloaded the zip, so that's the same as a pull. But when I'll want to push I will still have this issue...

Comment: @LucyWeatherford, `ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa >~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` would generate the public key from your private key and save it to the indicated file -- see [this solution](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=99697). Please be sure to refer to the preson whose comment you're asking (using the "@" character, like `@kostix`) to get them *notified* about your comment. I've stumbled about these your comments almost by accident!